# error: called object is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I try to insert many values into a queue and delete the first value in the queue. 
However, I have an error when I want to print the queue after deleting values.

There is my code:

```
char queue[100];
int i=-1;

int *delete_queue(int value){

    int j;
    for(j= 0; j< 10; j++){
    queue[j]= queue[j+1];   
    }

    return queue;

}

void insert_queue(int value){

    i= i + 1;
    queue[i] = value;

}

void print_queue(int *p){

    int v;
    for(v =0; v < 5; v++){
        printf(">> %d \n", *p(v+1) );
    }

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //int v ;
    int *new_queue;
    insert_queue(33);
    insert_queue(22);
    insert_queue(11);

    new_queue= delete_queue(33);
    print_queue(new_queue);
    // for(v =0; v < 5; v++){
    //  printf(">> %d \n", *new_queue(v+1) );
    // }

return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
delete_queue_test.c: In function ‘print_queue’:
delete_queue_test.c:33:23: error: called object ‘p’ is not a function or  
function pointer
printf(">> %d \n", *p(v+1) );
                   ^
```

please help me fix it, thank you.

Comment: I think you meant `p[v]` instead of `*p(v+1)`. BTW, having a global variable called `i` is a bad idea. Something like `queue_count` or `queueIndex` would be better.

Comment: thank you !  it works, and it also can be  *(p + v). I also have another problem that is `char queue[100];`. I switch  `char queue[100];` to  `int queue[100];`

Answer (score 1):

- Returning `int*` converted from `char*` (converted from `char queue[100]`) is bad. Use `int` for `queue`'s elements.
- As the error message suggests, `*p(v+1)` is invalid because `p` is a pointer to not functions but `int`, so function call operator `()` cannot be used to it. To access `v`th element of `p`, you can use `p[v]`.